# Unable to save array entry for list<text> column

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, cassandra, loopbackjs

I am using Cassandra datasource in loopback 3, and trying to store values in list datatype column of a table(keyspace) of Cassandra datasource. But while creating an entry from loopback explorer, we are getting **TypeError: Not a valid list value, expected Array obtained** '["Morning","Afternoon","Evening"]'

Here is my loopback model:

```
{
  "name": "Time",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "options": {
      "type": "array",
      "format": "list"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Tried debugging loopback-cassandra-datasource and saw **options** converted to string in params.

Data passed from loopback explorer:

```
{
  "options": ["Morning","Afternoon","Evening"]
}
```

Data logged from beforeRemote hook of the model:

```
{ options:
   [ 'Morning',
     'Afternoon',
     'Evening' ]
}
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "loopback": "3.26.0",
  "loopback-boot": "2.28.0",
  "loopback-component-explorer": "6.4.0"
  "loopback-connector-cassandra": "1.7.1"
}
```

The **typeof options** is object. I was debugging loopback cassandra connector and found **typeof options** as string in **encoder.js** of cassandra-driver node module. We have migrated from MongoDB to Cassandra and didn't face any issues for MongoDB driver. To what type or which format do I need to set for options property? Please let me know if any additional information required. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please console log the data you are trying to insert, and post that here.

Comment: Logs are added in the post. Found type casting taking place after debugging loopback cassandra connector, but not sure where it happened. Please let me know if any additional info required. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the `remote` method definition? Like `Model.remote('funcName',...etc)`?

Comment: I used before remote hook for all methods using double asterisks. `Time.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, modelInstance, next) {
 const data = ctx.args.data;
 console.log(data.options);
 console.log(typeof data.options);
 next();
});`
```

Comment: Okay, so you are using the built in insert remote method?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It throws an error while creating the records.